# Add any but same password to pdf files in a folder using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I would like to add a single password or password protect all the pdf files in a particular directory for the files starting with particular word "Retail.. " using batch script.
Updated my code but this does not apply password to my pdf file.

```
@echo on
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set filepattern="CE*.pdf"
REM cd /d C:\reports
cd C:\Desktop
for %%F in (%filepattern%) do (
set pass=test
::echo pdftk "%%~nxF" cat output "PDF\R_%%~nxF" owner_pw !pass!
pdftk CE.pdf output CE.pdf user_pw !pass!
)
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: We don't give out code. We help people who have written their own code and are having problems. ***Show Code***

Comment: What program are you using? What have you tried? Where have you encountered difficulty?

Comment: Hi abelenky, I am trying with the batch script. As i need to bulk password protect pdf files. I updated small piece of code in my comments.

Comment: @user7471208, you don't put your code in comments.  You edit your question.

Comment: Sorry but I have edited my question now.

Comment: You seem incapable of answering a basic question, but I will answer it for you:  *"What program are you using?"*  ***"I am using PDFTK to encrypt the files."***

Comment: Why are you only applying a password to `CE.pdf`? I thought you wanted to apply it to ALL files: `%~nxF`?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo on
set filepattern="Retail*.pdf"
set pass=test
cd C:\Desktop
for %%F in (%filepattern%) do (
    pdftk %%~nxF output PDF\%%~nxF owner_pw %pass%
)
```

This should encrypt:

`RetailQuotes.pdf` to `PDF\RetailQuotes.pdf`

Comment: I installed pdftk from the below path and i tried running this code but it didnt work   https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: *"didn't work"* is a whole lot of detail and description. (sarcasm) I'll provide as much help to you as the detail you provided to me (*none*).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pre-create a folder named “PDF” for output to work properly.